# Invoke-RestMethod a boolean value

Tags: powershell, variables, powershell-5.1

Using Powershell 5.1

I'm trying to post my body that includes a Boolean

```
  $body= @{ 
            "file"= $filePath 
            "name"= $fileName.name
            "booleanValue" =   $true
          }

$response = Invoke-RestMethod  -Uri $uri -Headers $headers -Method POST -body $body
```

The issue i'm having is the booleanValue not translating correctly, I have it working in my Postman test but I unable to get it working in my powershell.

I have tried 0 or 1 for it, 'true' and assigning a variable to [bool] but unable to handle it correctly in my typescript service.

Thanks for the help in advance,

Comment: Can you show details for the working postman request?

Comment: Use the string true : "booleanValue" =   "true"